# Using Cloudfront as a HAProxy backend server using https

Tags: https, haproxy, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront resource sitting in front of my S3 bucket. It's accessible at —

```
https://<id>.cloudfront.net
```

but if I hit —

```
<id>.cloudfront.net:443
```

I get a 400 Bad Request. I want to point to CloudFront in my HAProxy configuration, but I can't use the `443` port because of the above-mentioned issue. Nor can I use the `https` URL protocol in the server statement.

```
backend my_cloudfront_app
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000
    server my_server <id>.cloudfront.net:443 ssl verify none
```

How can I hit HTTPS cloudfront from this server block in HAProxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it the same question as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935547/using-cloudfront-as-a-haproxy-backend-server-with-https

I assume You will need to add some infos to the request headers for the cloudfront backend.

This example works with HAProxy 2.0

```
backend my_cloudfront_app
    http-response set-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000

    # Add backend header for cloudfront backend request
    http-request set-header Host <id>.cloudfront.net

    # maybe you will need to add a S3 prefix to the request path
    # http-request set-path <CLOUDFRONT_S3_Prefix>%[path] 

    server my_server <id>.cloudfront.net:443 sni str(<id>.cloudfront.net) ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 0):

haproxy assumes the connection to the backend is done via http. In order to connect to a backend via https, you would need a `ssl` after the ip:port part in the `server` config:

```
server micros-amkt-frontend <id>.cloudfront.net:443 ssl verify none
```

NOTE: I'm including some extra parameters (`verify none`) I found in an example as I couldn't find further documentation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've already tried adding a `ssl verify none`. The issue here is that `<id>.cloudfront.net:443` is inaccessible even via a curl, while `https://<id>.cloudfront.net` is

Comment: Just to clarify, even with curl and using https, `https://<id>.cloudfront.net:443` is not accesible (returns 400 error). Then try forcing the host header in haproxy: `http-request set-header Host <id>.cloudfront.net` without the port or check if CF allows you to add the host header with the port to the list of allowed names (that is probably a security feature, since browsers would not send the default port).

Comment: `https://<id>.cloudfront.net:443` — curl works
`https://<id>.cloudfront.net` — curl works
`<id>.cloudfront.net:443` — curl fails

Comment: Why would CF respond at 443 if you try to reach it without https?